# Calling C function from .so file by memory address from go module. (cgo)

Tags: c, go, cgo

I have an old .so file with a very complex clang parser in it and I have to call it from a go module.

```
    ...
    lib := C.dlopen(C.CString("./resources/bin/parser.so"), C.RTLD_LAZY)
    functions_address := C.dlsym(lib, C.CString("parse"))
```

Comment: `C.call(functions_address)`?

Comment: I have found a workaround. I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by defining a C typedef, creating a helper method and passing the "functions_address" to that helper method which calls the other function by reference

```
typedef char (*parse) (char *file);

char bridge (parse p, char* file) {
        p(file);
}
```